# MS Dynamics CRM 2012: Script Editor Enhancements

Tags: javascript, editor, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been trying to find some more information about the next Microsoft Dynamics CRM product (2012 / 6). Mainly I am interested in any enhancements that will be made to the scripting editor.

There was great improvements between version 4 and 5 (2011), the most welcome for me being the ability to share script functions across form/field events.

What I really miss though is the complete lack of formatting in the editors. Yes, it would be great to have intellisense and the likes, but I would be happy just to settle for a better formatting function (auto-tab) and some highlighting for better readability.

Does anybody have any information on where Microsoft is going in this respect? I am happy to do some reading if anybody has a good link to share.

Maybe there is a 3rd party tool that has good integration? I would be interested in taking a look into some of them if they exist, or somebody can recommend through experience.

Looking forward to hearing other peoples opinions on this one.

Thanks

Comment: @PeterMajeed Am I missing something here? As far I can tell at the moment (the last week of 2012), there's no such thing as CRM 2012. There **will be** Polaris version (sort of 2013, as far as I understand) but 2012, to my knowledge, glows with its absence. What gives?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: it was the OP that suggested a CRM 2012 product, not me. See vtbassmatt's response for a CRM insider's view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791822/ms-dynamics-crm-2012-script-editor-enhancements#comment9702507_7940583

Comment: @PeterMajeed I know. I just wanted to poke you on the question to get your attention. Also, I've voted up your reply and I have high hopes for the JS publishing software you mentioned below. Clicking add-pick-save-publish drives me (more) insane...

Comment: @KonradViltersten: yeah, the software worked pretty well for me and my team. It's a little while away from being a plug-and-play app for every possible organization I think, but at least you can modify the source when/if necessary.

Comment: @PeterMajeed I'm checking out the page but there's one thing I'm not clear about. The software we're discussing - is it a plugin to VS (so that the retrieval/publishing is done by a click on a button from VS or is it a stand alone tool to download/upload files (which one can edit between those two operations)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a modified version of Tanguy's [JavaScript Web Resource Manager for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2011/06/new-tool-javascript-web-resource.html) project to store, edit, and publish my JS files, and I use Patrick Verbeeten's [XRM intellisense js](http://www.patrickverbeeten.com/pages/ContentItemPage.aspx?id=31&item=118&p=true) for intellisense.  It's mostly seamless/painless, with the biggest bottleneck in deployment speed being the time it takes for the js files to publish.  Other than that, no real complaints here.

Comment: Great links thanks. I will give these a try shortly. I am going to leave the question unaccepted for a few days to see if I get any more hits, but I will be back at some point to accept an answer - so far you're winning ;)

Comment: I am trying to create a connection (with the web resource manager) to an online crm instance. Do you have any idea what I need to put in the "server" field? I am trying "<company>.crm4.dynamics.com" but it says "The remote name could not be resolved: dev.<company>.crm4.dynamics.com"... any ideas?

Comment: @musefan Hopefully someone else will be able to chip in here - we use the on-premise version, but I'm sure there must be some documentation somewhere that gives some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in script editor isn't scheduled for any enhancements that I know of right now.  However, the SDK includes the Developer Toolkit, which makes working with CRM in Visual Studio a heck of a lot easier.  Have a look here for documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372957.aspx

~Matt Cooper, program manager, Dynamics CRM

Comment: Also, there is no such product as CRM "6" or "2012".  The most recent release is the November 2011 update (codename R7).  Per our Statement of Direction, we're now on a twice-a-year cadence of releases so you can expect the next two versions (R8 and R9) to ship in spring 2012 and fall 2012 respectively.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for the link and the clarification about the release schedule.  I'll definitely have a look.

Comment: Thanks, and hope it helps.  Email me at my-first-name dot my-last-name @microsoft.com if there's anything else I can help with.